# Creating a table by using C# and MS Access SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a table in my database by I am being told that there is an error in syntax of my SQL. And I can't really tell where.

```
objOleDbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE PersonalData (" +
    "[DataID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ," +
    "[Type] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
    "[URL] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
    "[SoftwareName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
    "[SerialCode] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
    "[UserName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
    "[Password] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL";

objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing a closing parenthesis. Also, to make the code slightly more readable, consider using the `@""` construct, which allows multi line string literals:

```
objOleDbCommand.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE PersonalData (
    [DataID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Type] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [URL] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [SoftwareName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [SerialCode] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    [Password] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)";
```

Comment: Duh! Yes I did... I need a break, I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket at the end.  IE:

```
  objOleDbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE PersonalData (" +
                "[DataID] AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ," +
                "[Type] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
                "[URL] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
                "[SoftwareName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
                "[SerialCode] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
                "[UserName] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ," +
                "[Password] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)";

            objOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```